# InfoPath alternative on O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

My company is switching to SharePoint on premise. We got the O365 package and I was searching how could we create custom input form and confirmation form like with InfoPath 2013. Is there a way to edit that form for a list? How do edit Flows email template? Like with those approve and reject buttons.

Comment: Do you ask for alternatives for InfoPath on Office365? if yes!, so you should check [PowerApps](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/) if I didn't get your point please specify your issue in more details to can help you faster!

Comment: SharePoint On Premise 2019 ?

Comment: @MohamedEl-QassasMVP you got it right. I am trying to figure it out how to make it for desktop? All I get is phone sized canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unfortunately,** you **can't** convert or migrate from PowerAppas to InfoPath form.

As it's mentioned at [SharePoint Designer 2016 and InfoPath 2016 in SharePoint Server 2016, What’re the alternatives?](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/did-you-consider-powerapps-is-a-replacement-for-sharepoint-designer-and-infopath-in-sharepoint/)

> Power apps is a cloud service that can't be used with on-prem like
>   InfoPath, meanwhile, you can create a **gateway** to get data from on-prem
>   to the cloud!

Therefore, you can't migrate PowerApps to InfoPath forms and you need to start your business logic from scratch using SHarePoint Designer workflow and InfoPath and that will require enterprise edition!

---

Regarding the ability to do the same business logic with InfoPath, I think you can **BUT** without the same simplicity and functionality and of course, there are more functionalities in InfoPath that not available in PowerApss and vice-versa.

> You can also check The [key differences between InfoPath and PowerApps](https://collab365.community/infopath-vs-powerapps-differences/).

So I suggest trying 3rd party tools like Nintex or K2 to build your forms and business logic in an effective manner but sadly, it would be costly!